# jQuery How to control, does an element exist in document?

Tags: jquery

I want to control does an element exist in document with its ID, when page is loading. I tried code which is below, but i failed.

```
   if($(':not(#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>)')){
     alert("Object is null")else{alert("Object is exist")}}
```

Thansk for your helps already now.

Comment: Thank for your all suggests. I try every suggest in my asp.net project. There is no problem in js side but when i use postback method consist a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just use directly the `length` property, as suggested on the [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F):

```
if ($('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').length) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Read from this post (courtesy of `jakemcgraw`):

[Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return jQuery(this).length>0;}

if ($('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').exists()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest I can think of when using JQuery is this:

```
if ($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").length == 0){
        // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for the selections size() would suffice.

```
if ($("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").size() > 0) {
   alert("Object is null")
} else {
   alert("Object is exist");
}
```